# Additional spaces in text definition

Tags: qt, text, qml, qtquick2

I define a long text. I'd like to add line breaks to increase readability:

```
    Text
    {
         text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. 
                Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. 
                Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue."
    }
```

Can I be sure that no redundant spaces from the indents will be shown by the Text component (in any situation)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as following:

```
Text
{
     text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. " +
           "Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. " + 
           "Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue."
}
```

Or according to the [ECMA(page 149)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf) you can use symbol to mark current line as to be continued on next line '\' :

```
Text
{
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. \
Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. \
Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue."
}
```

In last case you should start new line from the beginning of the string to not include any space characters.

Comment: It should be unnoticeable

Comment: And what about the main question: is there any risk of this spaces appearing in my case? I didn't notice any when written my way.

Comment: I have tested your code on my machine and the spaces and new line character really appears. According to the script spec you can use LineContinuation in strings constants declaration. You can check page 149 of the doc http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf  . And check my updated answer for example.